# What is the general function to add a Widget area (not of a particular type)?

Tags: theme-development

I'm very new to WP theming and I know there are several types of functions to add Widget areas.

The following one, for example, adds a widget area dedicated for menus:

```
# functions.php (register a new widget area):

    function newMenuWidgetArea() {
    register_nav_menus(
    array (
    'my-custom-menu' => __('newMenu'),
    'extra-menu' => __('newMenu')
    )
    );
    }
    add_action('init', 'newMenuWidgetArea');

# header.php (declare widgets in the new area to appear):

    <?php
    wp_nav_menu(array (
    'theme_location' => 'newMenu',
    'container_class' => 'newMenu')
    );
    ?>
```

### The problem:

I don't want to add custom menus manually for example, so I don't look for a functions that add menus and their widget areas manually.

I wish to add menus from the GUI, hence I am looking forward to use a function that create global widget areas that can serve for any purpose, and then I will add into them anything I wish directly from the GUI (menu, text area, or whatever other widget).

### The question:

What is the general function to add a general-purpose/multi-purpose Widget area?

The one I have for now creates a menu. not a widget area in which I could place widgets.

Comment: what is the "widget area" that you ask about? your question seems to be all about menus. Please edit the question and clarify what is that you mean

Comment: This might help: https://codex.wordpress.org/Widgetizing_Themes

Comment: I've now edited the question @MarkKaplun

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding on mikesars answer, afterwards, one needs to Place the widget in a template file like header.php (for example).

So it would be:

***functions.php:***

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
  register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Name of Widgetized Area',
    'before_widget' => '<div class = "widgetizedArea">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
  )
);
```

*Template file:*

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || 
!dynamic_sidebar("Widgetized Area") ) : ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think youre looking for the `register_sidebar`function.

```
if ( function_exists('register_sidebar') )
  register_sidebar(array(
    'name' => 'Name of Widgetized Area',
    'before_widget' => '<div class = "widgetizedArea">',
    'after_widget' => '</div>',
    'before_title' => '<h3>',
    'after_title' => '</h3>',
  )
);
```

with this you get a new WidgetArea in the widget section in the backend.

You would then need to choose where you want it to appear. For example, if you would want it somewhere in the header, add this there, with this could:

```
<?php if ( !function_exists('dynamic_sidebar') || !dynamic_sidebar("Name of Widgetized Area") ) : ?>
<?php endif;?>
```

Comment: Oh, I came across this but was sure, because of the name, that these are always in vertical (from the left or from the right). Maybe it's just me effected by the terminology common in Bootstrap, instead of Wordpress.

Comment: yeah the name is confusing. but in fact its just creates an area where you can place widgets.